# (1045, "Access denied for user)

Tags: mysql, django, heroku

I am trying to connect my Django app on Heroku to an external MySQL database server of another domain. I have already set up the config variable but the Heroku app doesn't seem to be using them.

I get the error below. It seems the Heroku app is using an amazonaws host and not the one I have specified on the DATABASE_URL. Please help

(1045, "Access denied for user 'dekacoke_dekate'@'ec2-3-85-219-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)")